# launching new activity keeping launcher activity in backstack

Tags: android, android-activity

There are two activities in my application Activity A ( Launcher Activity) and activity B. first i launch an application(A activity) . onBackpress(),i am moving A to backstack. I am launching other app and firing intent from there  to launch  activity B. Now activity  A which is in background is getting launched first then B is coming top of it.

How to make activity A to be in backstack and opens only activity B on firing intent from other application?

Comment: I know the problem, but I cannot remember the solution. However I'm quiet sure that there are some dublicates of your question.

Comment: Can you please post your code so that its clear for us as to what excatly you are trying to do and it would also be useful for us to give you a solution

Comment: @rekire : please share duplicate questions if you know any...